# When I try to output the customerName and customerID of people who have rented films priced 2.6, it outputs the name and ID of everyone

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, datatable

```
SELECT customerId, customerName
FROM customerRentalinfo, film
WHERE filmPrice = 2.6;
```

This is the table that I have created for the movie rental system. rental id, customer id, customer name, customer email, rental date, film name, quantity, film price, total price are the entities of this table:

[image: This is the table that I have created for the movie rental system. rental id, customer id, customer name, customer email, rental date, film name, quantity, film price, total price are the entities of this table.]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be relationships in the database design that support the expected outcome.  The design needs to be revisited as it's not right as it stands

Comment: And how are the tables CustomerRentalInfo and Film linked with each other?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  You cannot answer the question with the given data model, assuming that the column names are even remotely related to what they actually represent.

In particular:

- The customer is attached to `rentalId`, which leads to `filmName`.
- The two tables with a price have no film id or name at all.  They are just prices sitting on unidentified rows.

The data model has other issues as well:

- Customer information is repeated separately for each rental.  Such information should be in a single `Customers` table.
- The price would normally be in only one table.
- The `films` table would normally have an id and a name.
- In fact, every table should have an `id`.

And no doubt other problems as well.

I will also throw in that you should be using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.